# NASM instruction not supported in 32-bit mode

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, sasm

I am using VirtualBoxVM and downloaded ubuntu(64-bit) in linux. I use the platform SASM for my assembly code in NASM in x86 mode. However when I try the use 64 bit operands (such as rax, rbx...) it gives the error "instruction not supported in 32-bit mode".

I tried fixing it but i don`t know what the problem is. Is the problem in my code or is it NASM? An hoe
w can I fix it?

Comment: 64-bit registers require 64-bit mode.  Configure SASM to build your code as 64-bit if that's what you want to write.  (You want it to run `nasm -felf64` rather than `nasm -felf32`.)